# Responsive layout with grid, html tables, media-queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, media-queries

Which is the better way to create a responsive website among grid, media queries, and HTML tables.

Answer (score 1):

often neglected by developers when it comes to responsive websites: Typography.
Typography!

@media (min-width: 640px) { body {font-size:1rem;} }

@media (min-width:960px) { body {font-size:1.2rem;} }

@media (min-width:1100px) { body {font-size:1.5rem;} }

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to create a responsive behavior in css, you gave some good examples for them.
Personally, I'm using the `Flexbox` and `Grid` display methods to align html containers and contents, and by using `Media Queries` i can make them interact responsively for any device.

For example, if you wanna render a cards-based container, meaning there will be multiple `div` elements with their own contents, aligned in a straight line, i would use the `flex-wrap` property to break them instead of overflowing to one of the page sides. If the cards are getting small enough for the page, i'd use the `vw` value for my card's width at a certain page width, using `media queries`.

Of course you can have your own preferences for different responsive methods, and there are a lot you can search on the internet, i just gave some of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries and flex,
Some example breakpoints,

```
// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and down)
@media (max-width: 1200px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and down)
@media (max-width: 992px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and down)
@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and down)
@media (max-width: 576px) { ... }
```